# Serialised data bus using 74-series logic?

Tags: serial-bus

I’m looking for ways to serialise an I/O data bus write. This is for an x86 embedded system, where I have several on-board devices (accessed via I/O ports) that I want to situate some distance away from the main system, with minimal cabling.

This isn’t a student/homework question, despite it perhaps looking like one.

In a computer, software can instruct a CPU to write a byte (or larger) to an I/O port. This results in data on 8 signal lines (a data bus) that can be connected to a data latch within a peripheral.

I’d like to relocate this peripheral some distance from the CPU. Rather than having 8 data lines (wires) plus ground running over several metres, the data should be sent serially over a smaller number of lines (data, clock and ground as a minimum), and converted back to 8 bits in parallel at the far end.

I’m interested in a generic solution, not something that connects a known computer to a known peripheral where a proprietary solution may already exist. And discrete logic is preferable, at least to start with.

I wondered if I could use something like a 74HC165 to take an 8-bit input and serialise this, and a 74HC595 to convert that serial stream back to 8 bits in parallel. I’ve seen some examples of these being used with Arduino kit.

My simplistic use case above is write only. But a more generic solution would be bidirectional. And there would need to be some kind of acknowledgement signal so that a subsequent write operation wasn’t attempted until the previous one was completed fully. While my question above is for just 8 bits, I’d then scale this up to 32 bits or more.

Are there any approaches out there that might satisfy this requirement? Is what I’m describing already solved by SPI or I2C? I’ve yet to find an SPI data latch (e.g. a SPI-enabled 74HC373 type latch). A fully-fledged networking solution isn’t appropriate.

*Adding to the question, following some comments*: I have an initial use case in mind, where a legacy CPU board has an on-board header that connects to an on-board control/sensor device. I'm looking for a serialisation solution that goes between the on-board header and the control/sensor device that can then be relocated off-board, i.e. 2m to 5m away. While I can modify the software/firmware, I can't alter the existing hardware.

Comment: @periblepsis Your comments are helpful, no need to delete :-).
1. There's no DMA or DRAM concerns (no DMAC, SRAM only, it's not a PC).
2. I don't need to hold the bus. Having written to the port (e.g. out dx, al) I can wait (via software) until the far end has received the 8 bits and processed them

Comment: Sure, there are both SPI and I2C "I/O expander" chips. Microchip MCP23017 and MCP23S17, for example.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks! I'd looked for these, but my search terms didn't find them. 

Are you familiar with these parts to the extent that you know whether they can provide the sort of serialisation I'm asking about? I did look at the associated App Note for interfacing to a matrix keyboard, but that's only half of the solution.  Same as the Arduino examples above, they rely on a CPU providing the serial data.

Also, I noticed that these require configuration. That's fine for the CPU end. But in my scenario, the far end (e.g. a 16 bit sensor) is dumb, there's no option to configure anything.

Comment: Are you using x86 OUT instruction? This outputs both address and data, so is there some address decoding involved? IMO it would be much simpler to skip the serialization part, not use OUT, and just use SPI, I2C, or any other serial protocol... or just UART. Can you explain why you want to use OUT and not these?

Comment: @bobflux: Fair point, I could do this. But it would mean a new board design. At the moment I have a legacy board with an on-board data header that is connected to an on-board legacy control/sensor-type device. So I was looking to connect a "serialisation solution" to this header. The other issue with SPI/I2C is that my far end cannot be configured, it's dumb - no CPU/microcontroller - and I don't really want to redesign this. So I may need a simpler/more primitive soloution using 74 series parts that don't require any config - if that's possible

Comment: OK! That makes a lot more sense if you want it to be compatible with an existing board. What signals are available on the data header? I'm asking because if you want to read with IN instruction, then the CPU will have to wait until the serial transaction is done, so you need the ready signal. Is it a standard bus like PC104?

Comment: @bobflux: Thanks, it's a proprietary system. There's only a data bus on the header, plus device enable, read and write. No CPU control signals. My initial thinking was to add a long enough software delay after any I/O read or write to be sure that serial data had been sent or received and actioned. I can't redesign the hardware, but can access CPU control signals. However my preference is just to use a software delay.

Comment: Yeah software delay would work. You need a little state machine: detect pulse on write, latch data, serialize 8 bits... That's already quite a lot of 74HC chips. Would be much simpler with a small CPLD or a microcontroller as a one chip solution... probably simpler to use a serial port on your board if it has one.

Comment: *I'd looked for these, but my search terms didn't find them*.  [MCP23017](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/MCP23017-E-SP/894272) You implement I2C (or find option card to do it), chip does interfacing to I/Os.

Comment: With this kind of technology, running 8 data wires really is the most convenient way.

Comment: @user253751: In addition to the points above, there's also the risk of race hazards if I'm trying to serialise some of the control signals. An I2C or SPI solution won't work unless there's an I2C/SPI enabled 74xx373 latch, not something more flexible that requires config by a MCU. The more I look into this, the more I tend to agree with you...

Comment: An I/O port sort of implies a latch.

Comment: I may suggest something like the Texas instrument part SN65HVS882

Comment: @user69795: Thanks for the suggestion, it doesn't fully address the need. I've now found a solution, and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I’m answering my own question. To restate and simplify the use case (always easier to do after comments have been made):

There’s a legacy x86 CPU board. This has a 40 pin header that an onboard sensor connects to. The sensor is relatively dumb (no CPU/MCU), and uses the CPU's 32-bit data bus to exchange data, along with some control signals. The sensor needs to be relocated some distance from the CPU board. A 40 core cable is not ideal, and would need a lot of screening for noise.

I was looking for ways to serialize the data bus, and some of the control signals if possible without introducing any race hazards.

My initial thinking was to use 74-series parallel-to-serial and serial-to parallel converters. This looked onerous. Then wondered if an SPI or I2C based approach might work. But can’t find an SPI/I2C-enabled 74xx373-type latch. You can register-configure a more complex part to look like one – but my sensor is dumb, so that wasn’t an option.

I started looking at how a laptop’s main board connects to its LCD display, where the data is serialized so that only a small number of wires are passing through a screen hinge. While most solutions were FPGA-based, I came across the Fairchild FIN12AC/FIN24AC family of SerDes (Serializer/Deserializer) logic devices. These requires no software config, and provide a generic 12/24-bit bi-directional capability. They use differential signalling which is a bonus.

This looks like an almost exact solution for my use case. Another contender is the TI DS92LV16/DS92LV32 family, which has more availability. There are other discrete SerDes devices that appear more dedicated to specific industry needs.

I've found a few other posts that mention SerDes. I'd like to add SerDes as a tag to my original post, but don't have a high-enough points score yet.

Comment: This part might not be so easy to obtain, especially in qty of ones and twos. Also the packages are tiny, 5 x 5 mm and with dense pinouts and might cause grief.

Comment: @DDuck: Yep, I saw that. It's in a 5mm MLP/QFN package, or BGA. But I could use an adapter. Availability is somewhat limited. Digikey stocks them, but as a bulk purchase. AliExpress seems to have some in stock. There are other (probably better) options, such as the TI DS92LV16/DS92LV32 family, which has more availability. I’ve updated my answer to note this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified bit rate, I can offer a classic solution - a UART. A classic part would be the 6402. Bidirectional with two wires and everything is TTL compatible. The likely drawback is the bit rate - 125 kbps. Although there are versions which contain small FIFOs, so that can mitigate the issue if your communications are bursty.

Comment: Thanks, you're spot on about the bit rate issue. It's the CPU's data bus that needs extending. While <10 Mhz, the 6402’s 125 Kbps wouldn't be suitable. Higher speed UARTs may require register config, which isn’t an option. The SerDes devices identified appear to offer other advantages. They’ve been designed specifically for this purpose without needing a lot of additional logic. There’s no register config required. Their transmission clock is triggered/encoded by the data. They use differential signalling. All of which gives confidence that data will be transferred coherently.